# The pronunciation of the word "honest" is with "h" or without?

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know and to get some information about the pronunciation of the word "**honest**".

Some people told me that it's pronounced without the first letter "h" (as if: **onest**) but some told me that it's pronounced with the "h" as a full form pronunciation (**h**onest). Who's right? or does it depend on the country?

Comment: Where were they from? That might give you a clue.

Comment: Its phonetics is /ˈɒnɪst/, so it has vowel sound.

Comment: Did the person actually _say_ "**h**onest", or did this person simply _mention_ that it should be "**h**onest"?

Comment: Up until the late 19th century there was a perception that words shouldn't start with a vowel, so lots of words which start with a _vowel sound_ were spelt with a leading, but silent, `h`. However, from the late 19th century or early 20th century most English speakers (Londoners excepted) started to aspirate _most_ of these leading `h`s. This is why we write, for example, "a**n** historian" - because when English grammar took printed form it was pronounced "an istorian".  So I guess that 'honest' is one of the words which hasn't taken on this modern form.

Comment: @awj The spelling of _a/an historian_ depends on how one pronounces it, there is no "grammatical" rule that defines that it should be _an historian_. It simply depends on the local pronunciation.

Comment: @awj [this Q/A on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h) disagrees with your assumption. I'm not saying there are no people who spell _a(n) historian_ at odds with their pronunciation, but that is surely not because of some grammatical rule.

Comment: @oerkelens - I pointed out what I thought was an interesting historical titbit about English words beginning with `h` (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/a-historic-event-or-an-historic-event), I wasn't looking for a debate about notoriously mutable English grammar. You can argue which is right and wrong but I was simply pointing out the historical reason for this even being discussed today.  That's why I said that pronunciations change quickly in time - particularly across locales - whereas that which is printed changes much more slowly. This disparity produces these very debates.

Comment: It would not be honourable to pronounce 'honest' with an aitch

Comment: @awj when I read your explanation, it sounds as if you're saying `h`s were added to words simply because they started with vowel sounds. But we don't say "happle" or "hevery"—words like "honest" and "historian" were given initial `h`s because the the Latin words they descend from were once pronounced and written with initial `h`s.

Comment: There was no committee which decided which words would have `h` added and which wouldn't. It has been suggested that it might depend on the location origin of the word (from French of from German). As another example, consider the way that Americans don't aspirate the `h` at the start of 'herb' - this was true in the British Isles a couple of hundred years ago but the pronunciation then mutated in one part of the English world and not in another. However, British English doesn't require 'an' preceding 'herb'. No reason why, but that's English for ya.

Comment: @awj "Grammar," mutable or not, is not the issue. Pronunciation is. The contention that `h` was somehow prepended to `onest` because of  "a perception that words shouldn't start with a vowels" is just silly. The Latin _honestus_ predates the English word by millennia! We don't know how Latin sounded, but Spanish is considered by many to be the closest modern tongue to its mother, and the `h` is alao silent in _honesto._

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These sources

1. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/honest)
2. [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honest)
3. [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/honest)
4. [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/honest)
5. [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/honest)

say that the pronunciation is without the "h". I've never personally heard it with the "h". It's possible that some people do pronounce it with the "h", but I feel that they are the minuscule minority. So, I would say you are safest saying "onest", without the "h".

Comment: I have only heard one non-native speaker in my life pronounce it with /h/. Never heard a single native pronounce the H in *honest*.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking _maybe_ someone from like some random part of the American south might say this. _Maybe_, so I don't rule it out. Also, yeah, I can imagine a non-native speaker say this.

Comment: I'm actually finding it quite hard to pronounce with an "h" though it sounds to the inner ear significantly different to the Italian "honetto". I guess that's the aspiration.

Comment: @CharlieClark .. I think you meant "onesto". And it doesn't have an "h".

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm probably imagining the "h" as being vestigial.

Answer (score 9):

I've known it with a silent "h", so "an honest man" as opposed to "a helpful man".

The silent "h" occurs in some words of French origin:

> hour
>   heir
>   honest
>   honour

[but not in others](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/words-with-silent-h).

whereas a hard "h" will occur in words of Germanic origin

> hatchet
>   harness
>   helmet
>   hamlet

In terms of accents:

The French, when speaking English, will often drop the "h"s since it is not pronounced in French, e.g. Les Halles is pronounced "*lay al*". On the other hand, I have been asked in Paris by an American "Do you know where Les Halles (*les hal-les*) is? Had to think for a moment what they meant.

In BrE, an East London, South London, or Cockney accent also drops "h"s, because, well, that's what they do. So they may say "*elpful*" for helpful.

Comment: Your list of French origins should also include `hotel` which still can be aspirated. Unlike the more Germanic word so the same thing: `hostel` (the French form dropped the `s` at some point).

Comment: @CharlieClark I believe (but could be wrong) that one of the meanings of the circumflex in the French -- `hôtel` -- is indicative of the lost `s`.

Comment: Yes, French has for a long time kept such vestigial markers, also the `g` in `doigt` (from `digit`). But this is now optional.

Comment: Circular. If the *h* weren't silent in *an honest man*, the article would have to be *a* not *an*.  The choice between *a* and *an* depends on the leading sound of the following word. Likewise if the *h* in *helpful* disappeared, it would be *an helpful man*.

Answer (score 6):

There are words with initial "h" where the pronunciation of that "h" varies by region and dialect, but the word "honest" is not one of them.  Even in regions  (such as mine) in which initial "h" is scrupulously not dropped, "h" is never pronounced in "honest".

Necessary concomitant: we say "a historian" (where I gather Brits write "an historian"), but we say "an honest man".

Comment: What's your region? Just curious.

Comment: Boston, Massachusetts, which is in New England, in the Northeast USA.

Comment: Lol, I know where Boston is. Or were you just trying to get 15 characters?

Comment: I assume nothing. :)

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Boston is a small town in Linconshire, England.

Comment: Total side note: not all Brits write "an historian" and drop the h - my dialect doesn't - but I've never encountered an English speaker from anywhere who didn't drop the h in "honest".

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Even more confusingly for our ex-colonial friends across the Atlantic, Boston, England is only about 10 miles from New York, England - and New York only has a population of about 100. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York,_Lincolnshire

Answer (score 2):

There are three root words I know of that are spelt beginning with a H but are pronounced without any initial aspiration in those accents that have H-aspiration:

- Hour
- Honour (Honest, Honesty)
- Heir

These could be ancient imports from French (where the aspiration is not pronounced) who's pronunciation became standardised before other H-words were Anglicised.

Accents like Cockney that say "Eez at iz ouse" for "He's at his house" drop the H from all words AFAIK.

As others have alluded to, use of a/an before a H-word depends on pronunciation:

"A historian received an honour."

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on the country or region. The H is silent.

Comment: Horn, Helmet, Hamlet, Hive
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/horn_1?q=horn
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/helmet?q=helmet
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hamlet_1?q=hamlet
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hive_1?q=hive

Answer (score 0):

[This video on You-tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT7Ebp2pIBo) is also talking about it:

> "Mispronouncing words that they have *silent aitches* in English, is **a
>   very common mistake**"

That's why I think that those who told me to pronounce it with h (**h**onest), are wrong. So-far I didn't even one source that supports or gives evidence for correct pronunciation of **h**onest with h.

Comment: This appears to be providing context for your question ... or perhaps acts as a response to another comment or to a query in an answer. It doesn't seem like an answer (is "one person did it on youtube" really an answer to your question?). If it is additional context it should be an edit to the question, if it's a response to others here it should probably be a comment in the relevant place. If this is intended as an answer I think you'd need to explain why a single anecdote would indicate something other than an error.

Comment: It's added answer with more information and different attitude. It says in other words, that those who pronounce with aitch they are making mistake rather than represent a correct way of pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video on Youtube "Banshee Review - Commodore Amiga + CD32 - Kim Justice (Kimblitz #4) ".
The narrator, a British native speaker, clearly pronunces "honestly" with the H.

Comment: Hi Johnny, Welcome to ELL. Thank you for your answer. Please make It  easier for readers by creating a link to reference materials, rather than explaining where to find them. You can create a link using the Hyperlink icon (two interlocking links of a chain) above the editing panel.

Comment: Hi!  sorry, I will try to paste the link.   [This is the one when you can hear "honestly" pronunced with H at minute 3:19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq90o3x82W0).           [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGIP2YDeb3E)  is another video by the same guy where "honesty" is also pronunced with the initial H at minute 12:15).

Answer (score -1):

The Oxford Advanced learner's dictionary has two pronunciations for the word Honest. The British one is without H and the American one is with H. It looks like the place matters!

Comment: Really? Can you please cite exactly what you found in the dictionary? I can't imagine they'd make that mistake in the transcription of the American pronunciation. The online version has the pronunciation I would expect without an /h/: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/honest?q=honest

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/honest

Comment: I have the dictionary installed in a tablet. If you listen to the pronunciation the British version is without H and the American version has the H clearly pronounced.

Comment: I am American, 64 years old, and I have never in my life heard anyone pronounce "honest" with an audible "h". No dictionary in my house, British or American, including the 1889 American "Century Dictionary", lists any pronunciation but "onest". I am certain that your tablet dictionary is simply mistaken.

Comment: Have you listened to [the pronunciations they have online](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/honest)? Do you hear an "h" there?

Comment: I checked out the online pronunciations. I feel that the British one has the O sound predominant the American one has it like the a in the word alpha. The subtle difference could have led to my conclusion that H sound is present in the American form of pronunciation. Thank you Mr. Dan and User3081485 for correcting me.